# Cross compiling Linux kernel module

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

On Ubuntu Trusty x86_84, I have successfully been able to compile Linux kernel v3.7.1 for x86, 32 bit. However, as I am trying to build a simple kernel module by feeding the same kernel sources, it yields me a module for kernel v3.7.1 (expected), 64 bit.

How can I tweak the module building process to generate a 32 bit kernel module?

Comment: Did you look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/27148/compile-32bit-kernel-on-64bit-machine?

Comment: I did. The reason I didn't like it because I can compile whole Linux kernel, but when it comes to compiling a simple hello-world module, I have to resort to `chroot`.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226735/error-when-building-32-bit-linux-kernel-on-64-bit-linux-host and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501878/force-gcc-to-compile-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-platform?